# Cannot read property ‘latitude’ undefined

Tags: ionic3

I need help, is this an issue with `watchPosition()` or am I doing something wrong?

Here’s the code:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

 private lat: any;
 private lng: any;
 constructor( private geolocation: Geolocation ) {

 let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
watch.subscribe((data) => {

 // data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
 this.lat= data.coords.latitude;
 this.lng= data.coords.longitude;
},(error)=>{console.log(error);});

  }
```

Comment: Did you test it with an emulator? You must use a real device and not an emulator.

Comment: Can you see any error in console ? Are you running with `--livereload` option ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes i am using real device  and running with --livereload option. but i didn't get output.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get current latitude and longitude please use getCurrentPosition method

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
     });
```

Comment: thank you Jatin Devani,  by using below code it directly executing catch function  & getting catch error                    
  `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
     }).catch((e)=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(e));});`